# AnchorCMS installation fails

Tags: php, php-5.3, anchor-cms

When I've gone through the installation steps for Anchor CMS, I'm getting an error (after final step):

```
Uncaught Exception

Undefined variable: vars
Origin

install/routes.php on line 183
Trace

#0 /home/.../anchor-cms/install/routes.php(183): System\error::native(8, 'Undefined varia...', '/home/...', 183, Array)
#1 [internal function]: {closure}()
#2 /home/.../anchor-cms/system/route.php(165): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#3 /home/.../anchor-cms/system/router.php(158): System\route->run()
#4 /home/.../anchor-cms/system/start.php(46): System\router->dispatch()
#5 /home/.../anchor-cms/install/index.php(33): require('/home/...')
#6 {main}
```

Any suggestions? I'm running Linux 64bit (elementaryOS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have already resolved this, but the way I got around this was to remove the undefined variable from line 183 of the install/routes.php file completely.

```
return Layout::create('account' $vars);
```

So it then looked like this:

```
return Layout::create('account');
```

Refreshing the page will then allow you to create an account and login to the admin interface etc.